# Angular browser save large amount of data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, indexeddb, web-sql

I have a webapp that will need to be "a little disconnect" (some action can be made in disconnect mode, some need connection).

So i need to save in browser client a large amount of data (something around 4MB to 10MB, that exclude localstorage solution). A little precision, if that data can be save like a relational database thats better.

In angular, i test localforage solution (in websql mode for safari and in indexeddb mode in chrome, the two browser where i need my webapp work) but that was pretty slow (something around 2min05s just for save 5MB, thats seem incredible for 5MB...).

I will test a "pur websql" solution in that two browser, but if someone study a solution for that kind of project i will appreciate his help.

Thanks in advance for your answer and if you need more precision ask it to me.

Comment: Have used a combination of localforage + string compression in the past, compression takes a bit of time but with a background worker doing it, it did the trick and was able to compress 5mb to 1.7

Comment: Also, how have you tested that it takes 5 mins? takes me 131 milliseconds to save 5 million characters

Comment: I have test it with a webservice that send me the data (something between 40 to 50s for get it) and then save it with localforage (2min in android xperia z3 compact tablet with chrome and 1min10s with macbook pro with chrome).

Comment: Try with https://jsfiddle.net/3e6t6jfj/1/. Maybe what takes time is passing your data to string

Comment: That was with localforage (not localstorage) in indexeddb mode, maybe the problem came from localforage or my data (that was a list of complex data) or something.... (i continu to inverstigate but thanks for your help, that was pretty sur that can take less than 2min for save 5MB, if with your test with localstorage i can save it in 68ms :) )

Comment: Yeah, might have to do with the way you are using localForage. Note that doing a lot of small saves instead of a big save is expensive. And maybe this is related: https://github.com/mozilla/localForage/issues/315

Comment: I would recommend using indexeddbshim.js instead of localforage. I never used localforage, but indexeddbshim is quite fast. It uses IndexedDB, but if the browser doesn't support it (e.g. IOS) it defaults to WebSQL. (Edit to add: I have a similar situation to you: using Angular to store offline data that must work on both Android and IOS)